# URLs to file name conversion

Tags: ruby

I have 10 million web-page URLs, and I want to save their HTML as a file. Operating systems are quite restrictive on what I can use in my file name. I want some system to map the URLs to alphanumeric representations to store in a key-value database with a low probability of generating duplicate entries. I need a solution that can scale, and that is either:

1. Some encoding scheme (Windows for example, has restrictions of how long a filename can be so too big URLs can produce big encoded strings)
2. Some feature of the stdlib which would have very small chances of producing duplicates (and map random_string => url_path in a key-value database).

I came up with the following solutions:

- Use base64 encoding. This produces big strings for big URLs.
- Use Secure Random to generate urlsafe base64. I don't know how many combinations are there until I get duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think SHA in hexadecimal representation is the standard way in cases like this. It gives a fixed length.

```
sha = Digest::SHA1.file(file).hexdigest
```

Comment: Digest::SHA1.hexdigest 'foo' seems to be for strings. What if I want to get this back from the SHA1 hash into the regular 'foo'?

Comment: Since you mentioned Secure Random, I interpreted that you do not need to get back the original string from the converted name. If that was not the case, then your question is misleading or does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Saving to disk is going to be an ever-growing list of headaches. Instead you need to use something better designed for the purpose; You should save the HTML to a database. Your lookups will be a lot faster, and the names won't matter at all. Even SQLite can handle this task nicely.

You'd need a field for the actual URL, one for a friendly name, generally the title of the page, and one for the actual HTML content.

I'd suggest looking at using the [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) gem, which would make this task extremely easy. Look through their documentation for more info and working examples.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
md5(base64(filename))
```

it should unique enough :)

Comment: What is it you think the `base64` brings to the party?